# AJAX function not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am new to RoR and AJAX, jquery etc. I am trying to make an ajax call in a view, but its not happening.

Corresponding controller(product_search_controller,rb) is:

```
def index
 @products = querySolr(params[:q])

 @productsProxy = Array.new

 if @products != nil
    @products.each do |p|
      @productsProxy.push(ProductProxy.new(p))
    end
 else
    @productProxy = []
 end

 @taxons = @productsProxy.map(&:get_taxonomy).compact.uniq

 respond_with("Search Results") do |format|
   format.js
   format.html
   format.xml { render :xml => @productsProxy, :only => [:name, :permalink, :description, :mrp], :methods => [:designer, :taxons, :price] }
 end
end
```

Corresponding view(views/product_search/index.hrml.erb) is:

```
<%= render :partial => 'products', :locals => {:products => @productsProxy, :taxons => @taxons, :scope => self, :scope_type => "Search"} %>
<%= render :partial => 'shared/inf_scroll', :locals => {:url => "?&page=", :total_count => @total_count} %>
```

/views/product_search/_products.html.erb:

```
<% if products.empty? %>
  <div class="not_found"><%= "No Products found for the selected query. Please try a different search." %></div>
<% elsif params.key?(:keywords) %>
  <h3><%= t(:search_results, :keywords => h(params[:keywords])) %></h3>
<% end %>

<% if products.any? %>
<div class="product_rows">
    <%= render :partial=> 'product_listing_feature', :locals => {:scope => scope, :scope_type => scope_type} %>
    <div id="ql_product"></div>
    <%taxons.each do |taxon|%>
                <ul class="products" data-hook class="products">
            <div class = "product_row">
                <h1><%=taxon%></h1>
                <% taxonProducts = Array.new %>
                <% products.each do |product| %>
                    <%@ptaxon = product.get_taxonomy%>
                    <%if @ptaxon == taxon%>
                        <% taxonProducts.push(product) %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
                <div class ="featured_product_list">
                    <ul class = "featured_products">
                    <div class = "page">
                        <%= render :partial=> 'product_listing', :locals=>{:collection=> taxonProducts} %>
                    </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

i.e it renders another partial _product_listing which has the following script:

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
       $("li#product_<%=product.productId%>").hover(
        function(){$("div#quick_look_<%=product.productId%>").css("visibility", "visible");}, 
        function(){$("div#quick_look_<%=product.productId%>").css("visibility", "hidden");}
        );
       $("div#quick_look_<%=product.productId%>").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });

    hide_sold_out({
      url: "<%= sold_out_status_taxons_url(@taxon) %>",
      data: {
        pids: "<%= collection.map(&:id).join(",") %>"
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Helper:

```
var hide_sold_out = function(options){
$.ajax({
url: options["url"], 
data: options["data"],
type: 'get',
dataType: 'text',
success: function(data){
  pids = data.split(',');
  for(var i = 0; i < pids.length; i++) {
    if($("li#product_"+pids[i]).children("div.info").children("span.offer.sold").length == 0) {
    $("li#product_"+pids[0]).children("div.info").append("<span class='offer sold'></div>");
    $("li#product_"+pids[0]).children("div.info").children("div.product_listing_info_hover").children("div.listing_buttons").html("");
}
}
},
error: function(data){
 console.log(data);
}
```

. I tried using the following in /views/product_search/index.js.erb:

```
$("ul.products").append("<div class='page'><%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'product_listing', :locals=>{:collection=> @productsProxy})) %></div></div>")
```

This didn't work. Then i tried:

```
<%@taxons.each do |taxon|%>
    <%taxonProducts = Array.new%>
    <%@productsProxy.each do |product|%>
            <%@ptaxon=product.get_taxonomy%>
            <%if @ptaxon==taxon%>
                    <%taxonProducts.push(product)%>
            <%end%>
    <%end%>
    $("ul.products").append("<div class='page'><%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'product_listing', :locals=>{:collection=> @taxonProducts})) %></div></div>")
<%end%>
```

But the AJAX call is not doing what its supposed to do. Please could someone help me debug this. Thanks

Comment: Where is you `AJAX` call?

Comment: If you apply Santosh's answer, do you get the same results? If so, do you know whether Ajax is actually firing?

Comment: @RichPeck : No, changes mentioned in Santosh's answer did not fix it. How can I check if Ajax is firing?

Comment: You can check by either putting an alert in your trigger event (& before Ajax is called) or by looking at your developer tools console in either Firefox or Chrome. I just looked over your code to see where you are calling Ajax, and it seems you've not attached it to any trigger event? Can you explain when you need Ajax to be called?

Comment: @RichPeck : I am getting `http://localhost:3000/taxons/sold_out_status.307171060?pids=1060513508%2C1060513997%2C1060515105%2C1060515107%2C1060515108 406 (Not Acceptable)` in developer tools -> console

Comment: Okay, what about if you go onto the "Network" tag -- it shows all the requests your browser is making. When you fire the Ajax, look for the request is makes & if it turns red, click on it (there is an error). Then you can click onto the "Preview" sub-tab, which will show you the page that was rendered, and should show the error you're getting! If you could let us know that error, it will be great!

Comment: There are 3 reds in the `network`. 406 for `http://localhost:3000/assets/dist/jquery-migrate.min.map`. Another for the one i mnetioned in the earlier comment and 404 for localhost:3000/undefined. No preview for any of the 3

Comment: @RichPeck : is my js.erb correct?

Comment: The `js.erb` looks okay, but you have a problem in where the ajax is calling

Comment: From the looks of your error, I'd say you're not calling the right URL in Ajax. If your ajax is pinging `localhost:3000/undefined`, it means you're not giving it the correct URL, and consequently will receive an error. Which URL are you trying to reach?

Comment: @RichPeck I added an aler in both `success` and `error` in `var hide_sold_out`. Surprisingly I am getting both the alerts. Also, adding alert(options.url) shows the correct url. I think the undefined is for something else

Comment: lol the plot thickens!!!! Have you got any live links you could show? There's something else at fault here, and I think it's systemic

Comment: @RichPeck : The results are coming with a sold_out tag on the top left, which I want to remove. But another finding, alert(options.data) shows [object Object]

Comment: Change `alert(options.data)` to `alert(JSON.stringify(options.data))` - it _should_ output the text

Comment: Thanks for the link - can I ask where you get the Ajax to fire?

Comment: @RichPeck : Do you mean the location of the helper?

Comment: Nooo, I mean how do I check the "network" calls etc on your live page? I need to see how your Ajax is performing and can't work out how :)

Comment: You can see everything in the developer tools i guess

Comment: @RichPeck : was able to fix this. The Ajax was working fine but there was a wrong codition somewhere in the view. Anyways thanks a lot for your time. Learnt a few new debugging tricks!

Comment: No problem! Your site looks really good!

Answer (score 1):

These

```
url: options["url"], 
data: options["data"],
```

should be

```
url: options.url,
data: options.data,
```